# Alphabetic Style of Bibliography - how to insert special letters in the first three letters

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem with the alphabetic style of the bibliography.

In the preamble I have defined:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
language=american,
maxbibnames=100,
maxcitenames=1,
backref=true,
abbreviate=true,
url=false,
sorting=nyt,
babel=hyphen,
style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

Problem: If the first author name of the bibitem contains a special character in the first three letters, like:

```
@article{Blonski,
author={P.~{B{\l}o\'{n}ski}},
title={xxx},
year = 2010}
```

the bibitem in the manuscript is abbreviated as `[Bł10]`. I would like to have `[Bło10]`. Similar Problem for example in case of:

```
@article{Koenig,
author={{M.~K\"{o}nig},
title={xxx},
year = 2007}
```

returns `[K¨07]` instead of `[Kön07]`.

What do I have to modify?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please note that the proper way to give the author is without the `~` between the initial and the last name, also Mr(s) König seems to have a superfluous curly brace in his/her entry.

Comment: Did you find in my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Why don't load `inputenc`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and simply use the characters `ł`, `ń` and `ö` in your `.bib` file?

Then use `biber` instead of `bibtex8`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
language=american,
maxbibnames=100,
maxcitenames=1,
backref=true,
abbreviate=true,
url=false,
sorting=nyt,
babel=hyphen,
style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Blonski,
author={Błoński, P.},
title={xxx},
year = 2010}
@article{Koenig,
author={König, M.},
title={xxx},
year = 2007}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Blonski}

\cite{Koenig}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

Otherwise, if you don't want to switch to `biber` you can try this code (you can even use `bibtex` instead of `bibtex8`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
language=american,
maxbibnames=100,
maxcitenames=1,
backref=true,
abbreviate=true,
url=false,
sorting=nyt,
babel=hyphen,
style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Blonski,
author={B{\l}o\'{n}ski, P.},
title={xxx},
year = 2010}
@article{Koenig,
author={K{\"{o}}nig, M.},
title={xxx},
year = 2007}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Blonski}

\cite{Koenig}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```